# How to open locked Samsung Galaxy S5?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, samsung, settings, security

Can anybody help me how to open locked Samsung Galaxy? I do not know, I had a fingerprint showing up and the alternative password. I had a keyboard showing numbers and alphabets. But now, it's totally different. it shows only numbers the problem is my password has alphabets?

Answer (score 0):

You can crack your screen password with this app of **Dr. Fone**. Visit this [Link](https://drfone.wondershare.com/reference/android-lock-screen-removal.html) and download the app that matches with your **Device Model**. **You don't need to root your device or enable USB Debugging, neither any custom ROM**. Just download the app of your device's model and connect it to PC then do whatever you want. Also you don't need to backup as it won't wipe your data.